# WPF is rendering data very slowly

Tags: wpf, performance, listview, data-binding

More than 8000 objects are getting binded to ListView control and a object has two properties.ie ID and Description).
LstViewTextBLocks is a Listview control whose itemsource is assigned to 'view' which is  of type ICollectionView

Data gets loaded fast in codebehind(as noticed in debugging) but while rendering the data it takes almost 6 minutes and also when the data is rendered while scrolling through it becomes very laggy.

```
<TabItem Header="data" Background="Gray" Name="textPicker" >
    <!--<local:TextPickerView/>-->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="Filter:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <TextBox Name="TextblockFilter1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
     Text="{Binding TextSearch,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" />

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">

            <**ListView** Name="LstViewTextBLocks" 
          VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" SelectionMode="Single"                                 
                      VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        **<GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}" />**
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </**ListView**>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

ItemsSource of my listview in the code behind was set like this:

```
this.LstViewTextBLocks.ItemsSource = this.View;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the ScrollViewer from your code. This ScrollViewer allows for the ListView to occupy all the height it needs for your 8000+ rows. This results in removing the virtualization from the ListView. ListView has its own Scrollviewer which will be triggered in, and will also help in virtualization and fast performance comparatively.

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="Filter:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <TextBox Name="TextblockFilter1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                 Text="{Binding TextSearch,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" />


            <ListView Name="LstViewTextBLocks" 
                      Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                          VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" SelectionMode="Single"                                 
                          VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}" />
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: it worked anyway with trial and error and thanks for the explanation.